# Clear PowerShell Sharepoint Cache?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have an odd problem:

I deployed a WSP package containing stuff and a site template using PowerShell

```
Add-SPSolution ...
Install-SPSolution ...
```

When now trying to create a new Site Collection, my template is visible and I can create a new site collection with my template.

When I try to look at all the installed site templates with PowerShell (`Get-SPWebTemplate`) **in the same session as before**, the new template does not appear!

The same goes visa-versa: When retracting/deleting the solution, I cannot create a new site collection with the template anymore since it's gone. But in the still open PowerShell session the template is still visible.

The only solution: Open up a new PowerShell session after the solution has been retracted/deployed - only in this "fresh" session, the changes are synchronized.

**My question is: How do I clear this PowerShell cache? How do I fetch the site template list directly from the server and not from some cache?**

Some other guy also came up with closing/re-opening PowerShell ([PowerShell caching leads to head-banging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2011/02/17/sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-solution-deploy-deployment.aspx)) - this can't be the solution...

*Disclaimer: [Cross post from "How to clear PowerShell Object Model Cache"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/b0d4ca93-e246-4e45-a840-2343fe2c72ee).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that PowerShell **is** actually caching some stuff in particular the `OWSSVR.DLL`.

There are two (and ½) ways to overcome the problem:

1. [Use a nifty PowerShell snippet to kill a Sharepoint thread and reload a DLL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/5ea46e07-a4b0-4bab-b698-9b6eeb695607)
2. Use a different PowerShell session started from within the first session
3. Use old-school stsadm to create the site as stsadm lives within another thread and hence "sees" the new site templates already

I went with method 2 ½ (denoted 3) as it is just the easiest using a one-liner stsadm instead of calling up yet another PS session.

Comment: can you develop the 2nd point ? I've tried enter-pssession, new-spsession but have troubles with WInRM (even if I run Enable-PSRemoting)

Comment: Don't know how this behaves via WinRM... Plainly stated when you just open a new powershell prompt via `powershell.exe -command "mycommand"` it works. Same as when you would run another `powershell.exe` manually. You would need to figure out a way to start another powershell shell [sic] to run your ccommands. I have resorted to 3. - use stsadm within my powershell script and everything is fine.

Comment: thanks. I'll give a chance to powershell.Exe -command but will fall back to stsadm if too complicated.

Comment: Somebody suggested `(Get-SPFarm).Uncache()` I yet have to try.

Comment: (Get-SPFarm).Uncache() did not work for my situation

Answer (score 0):

I can't check from here, but it's possibly got something to do with the web being cached in the current "assignment collection." Take a look at the Start- and Stop-SPAssignment commands. I'm not sure what the default assignment model is, but I'd try running "Stop-SPAssignment; Start-SPAssignment" to see if that will dispose of the current cached SPWeb being used to retrieve templates.

-Oisin